# ASP MVC, mutiple models with single controller / view with EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Can someone explain to me how to use multiple models with a single view in which each of the models represent a DB table?

What I've currently done is created a model file for each model.

Example Model:

```
[Table("Order")]
public class OrderModel
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public UserProfile Account { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int ShipLocation { get; set; }
    public string PONumber { get; set; }

    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public StatusModel Status { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the other model that encompases all the models to use in a single controller / view.

```
public class OrderPlacementModel
{
    public OrderModel OrderChild { get; set; }
    public OrderItemsModel OrderItemsChild { get; set; }
    public StatusModel StatusChild { get; set; }
    public MaterialsModel MaterialsChild { get; set; }
    public CategoryModel CategoryChild { get; set; }
    public PackModel PackChild { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question a little further? What do you mean by "use multiple models"? Does this mean display, edit, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult PlaceOrder()
{
  var viewModel = new OrderPlacementModel
  {
    OrderChild = new OrderModel(),//or fetch this object from your data source
    OrderItemsChild = new OrderItemsChild(),
    //...etcetera
  };
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

**Edit**

Or, if you've strongly typed your view to a `List<OrderPlacementModel>` instead of a single instance, you could do something similar to this:

```
public ActionResult PlaceOrder()
    {
      var viewModel = new List<OrderPlacementModel>();
      var model = new OrderPlacementModel
      {
        OrderChild = new OrderModel(),//or fetch this object from your data source
        OrderItemsChild = new OrderItemsChild(),
        //...etcetera
      };
      viewModel.Add(model);
      //lather, rinse, repeat for however many instances you need to send to your view.
      return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Ok the issue I'm running into is I get the following error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Test2012.Models.OrderPlacementModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Test2012.Models.OrderPlacementModel]'. 

Here is my Index view:

`code`@model IEnumerable<Test2012.Models.OrderPlacementModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.MaterialsChild
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>

Comment: @1tufgt Edited answer to address your comment

Comment: Ok so if my model is not strongly typed as a IEnumerable then is the proper way to set the view like this so I can pull the specific values from the child models?

`code`@model Test2012.Models.OrderPlacementModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@{
    var materials = Model.MaterialsChild.ToList();
    
    foreach(var item in materials)
    {
     <table>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 @item.Name
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>   
    }
}

Comment: How will you iterate Materials Child?  It doesn't appear to be an IEnumerable.

Comment: Well the OrderPlacementModel I've done the following. If you look at the material model.
`code`
    public class OrderPlacementModel
    {
        public OrderModel OrderChild { get; set; }
        public OrderItemsModel OrderItemsChild { get; set; }
        public StatusModel StatusChild { get; set; }
        public List<MaterialsModel> MaterialsChild { get; set; }
        public CategoryModel CategoryChild { get; set; }
        public PackModel PackChild { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Then it should work.  As long as you populate `MaterialsChild` (and all the other properties, for that matter)  before sending the model to the view you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should create a **view model** for the view that encompasses the fields from each model that you need to expose via the view. You can then map these in your controller. I would keep your **mapping classes** completely ignorant of your **view models**. Keep your views independent of your data model.

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int ShippingLocation { get; set; }

    public List<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int Title { get; set; }
}
```

Note how I have created a view model for the order and - to allow the order have multiple items - have separated these out into a separate model class. Now, you can type your view to `OrderViewModel` and use as many instances of `ItemViewModel` as your require.

You can then map your viewmodels to database entities from your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfirmOrder (OrderViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (ItemViewModel item in model.Items)
        {
            /* Create instance of OrderItemsModel (or whatever your
            DB mapping class is), populate with appropriate data
            from 'item' and commit to database. */
        }

        OrderModel order = new OrderModel();
        order.OrderId = model.OrderId;
        order.UserId = model.UserId;
        order.Date = model.Date;
        order.ShipLocation = model.ShippingLocation;

        /* TODO: Commit new order to database */

    }
}
```

Doing things this way adds a little overhead to your initial development time but allows you a great deal more flexibility as you aren't forced to mould all of your views to the shape of your entity classes.

Comment: But I'm initially using the models to setup my code first ef database.

Comment: Which is fine, but the models you use to map your database tables shouldn't be the models you pass to the view - you should have dedicated view models for this and move property values from one to the other in your controller, as in the code I have provided.